# Filter a datatable using linq with Grouping and a column sum

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to filter a datatable using linq. Need to group data based on a column and sum another column, the result needs to be a datatable. I have tried the following code, it gives the dictionary of the output, but how I can get this as a datatable instead of a dictionary.

Working code:

```
Dim dicList As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal) = dtFilteredData.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Location")).
    Select(Function(drg) New With {.cc = drg.Key, .total = drg.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of Decimal)("Expenses"))}).
    ToDictionary(Function(p) p.cc, Function(s) s.total)
```

Tried for Datatable:

```
Dim dtOutResult As DataTable = New DataTable
dtOutResult = dtFilteredData.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(r) New With {Key .Col1 = r("Location")}).
    [Select](Function(g) g.OrderBy(Function(r) r("Expenses")).First()).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Did you look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868585/how-to-group-table-data-and-sum-by-multiple-columns-using-linq-or-another-approa?rq=1

Comment: Tried the same, but not working. I need with as enumerable since I am using it in a different tool. Tried the following one, but giving error as decimal does not have a property of CopyToDataTable

Dim result = dx.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("catalogid")).[Select](Function(group) group.Sum(Function(item) item.Field(Of Integer)("backorder")).CopyToDataTable())